# Migrating from JBoss to TomEE. CMT are not woking at all

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, apache-tomee

I am new to TomEE. I am trying to migrate from JBoss 4.2.3 GA to TomEE PLus 1.7.1. I have developed all my EJBs using EJB 2.0 spec. All EJB are Statekess session beans. I have a few EJBs as BMT and are working fine. But CMT EJBs are not working at all.

tomee.xml

```
<Resource id="TPDDS" type="DataSource">    
JdbcDriver=com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLDriver
JdbcUrl=jdbc:JSQLConnect://dbamigratedb/database=shoppingcart/ssl=mandatory
UserName=prao
Password=pass
jtaManaged=true
validationQuery=select 1 from account
maxWaitTime=30000
maxActive=100
testOnBorrow=true
</Resource>

<TransactionManager id="myTransactionManager" type="TransactionManager">
adler32Checksum = true
bufferSizeKb = 32
checksumEnabled = true
defaultTransactionTimeout = 10 minutes
flushSleepTime = 50 Milliseconds
logFileDir = txlog
logFileExt = log
logFileName = howl
maxBlocksPerFile = -1
maxBuffers = 0
maxLogFiles = 2
minBuffers = 4
threadsWaitingForceThreshold = -1
txRecovery = false
</TransactionManager>
```

The Exception I get is:

```
Jul 29, 2015 11:50:59 AM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyResource
INFO: Closing DataSource: TPDDS
Jul 29, 2015 11:50:59 AM     org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil handleSystemException
SEVERE: EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: zip file closed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.ensureOpen(ZipFile.java:415)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry(ZipFile.java:160)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getEntry(JarFile.java:208)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getJarEntry(JarFile.java:191)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:757)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.classloader.URLClassLoaderFirst.loadInternal(URLClassLoaderFirst.java:177)
    at org.apache.openejb.util.classloader.URLClassLoaderFirst.loadClass(URLClassLoaderFirst.java:127)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.<init(LoggingEvent.java:159)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:826)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to show more of the stack trace because I suspect that you actually have a deployment failure here

Comment: Agreed - you've shown us the application tries to log something, loads a class in the process, and fails on the classloading because it cannot open a JAR. Is there anything else amiss in the logs from earlier than this? And is there a "caused by ..." clause in this stack trace?

Comment: This is the startup logos

Comment: I am seeing warnings TomEE starts up.


org.apache.openejb.config.ReportValidationResults logResults
    WARNING: WARN ... TestDeliveryBSEJBBean: Ignoring 1 invalid     <container-transaction> declarations.  Bean not using Container-Managed Transactions.
.....


Could this be the reason for this error.
In the CMT EJB, I have 2 stored Procedure calls. The first one gets called and while calling the second one it just does not run. So I do nit have a caused by. The "zip file closed" I get when the transaction times out.